# Filter a list and get also its opposite with linq

Tags: performance, linq, list

I have a simple question about list with LINQ. I searched about it and I haven't found anything like it.
I don't know which of them is better (in performance, for example).

```
list1 = list.Where(x => x.property).ToList();
```

Now I want the opposite list

```
list2 = list.Where(x=> !x.property).ToList();
```

I used this, but I am not sure.

```
list2 = list.Except(list1).ToList();
```

I've also thought getting a group and get both lists at the same time. It is a list with  two lists. Iterate over the first list is heavy.

What do you think about it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Gut reaction is that the Where options should perform faster than the Except, but when judging performance, the first rule is to test it yourself.

Comment: I agree with you, but I can't test it yet. I wanted to know if someone has a better point of view. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I'd just go with:

```
var listEqual = new List<YourType>();
var listNotEqual = new List<YourType>();

foreach(YourType item in list)
    if (item.Property)
        listEqual.Add(item)
    else
        listNotEqual.Add(item);
```

You *could* use

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(x => x.Property);
var list1 = lookup[true].ToList();
var list2 = lookup[false].ToList();
```

(even dropping the `ToList` if you don't strictly need lists) - this does only iterate your sequence once, although you need a little more code to handle the case where everything in your input is either `true` or `false`.

Comment: I didn't know ToLookUp() method. I will try it. Thanks.